# Designing fluid width pages

Tags: html, css-float, css

I'm building an internal web app and I want to make use of the entire page and as such have opted for a flexi-width design. The problem that I keep running into is that inline-block is causing things to be wrapped onto the next line in lower screen resolutions.

Am I doing something wrong or should I just ignore inline-block and float my elements? For reference I don't have to be concerned about browsers as I know all the users will be using the latest Chrome

**Edit**
http://jsfiddle.net/nH4GY/

This works fine at 1900x1080 but as you lower the resolution everything begins to wrap onto the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this type of functionality you can use `display:table-cell;`

```
body{
    display:table;
}
.pair
{
    width: 31%;
    padding: 1%;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/nH4GY/6/

For webkit based browsers like chrome you can use `Flexible Box Model` css .

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/GYrr7/

Comment: Can I safely assume that box model will be supported by webkit for the forseeable future?

Comment: Having looked at this a bit more, neither solution functions in terms of wrapping to the next row if I add more instances of .pair. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to increase the gap in between 2 div or maybe you can set min-width for a main container so it will never be smaller than a certain width

Answer (score 0):

If you have the page layout as per the example you have provided, you can just use float:left for the child div elements and also for the container.

If you then give your container, say 100% width, your child divs would try to respect that width and appear side-by-side on higher resolution screens AND would wrap only on lower resolution screens.

You can even block the wrapping to happen if you want, by just specifying a "min-width" property to the divs with some fixed value (say 100px)..

Hope that helps. Thank you.